# GASからAppSheetのユーザー情報を取得したい

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, google-api

多数のAppSheetを使用しており、各AppSheetのユーザー情報の一覧をスプレッドシートで見られるようにしたいと考えております。
GASから取得する形を考えておりますが、公式ドキュメントの"Use the AppSheet API"によればGASからテーブル操作はできてもユーザー情報は取得できないように読めます。

(1) そもそも、GASからAppSheetのユーザー情報を取得することは可能でしょうか。
(2) 可能な場合、APIエンドポイントはどちらになるでしょうか。

[参考]
https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10105768

Comment: こんな記事の情報が何か参考になるかも。[appsheetで作られたアプリの集中管理やログ収集方法について](https://www.appsheet-japan-community.com/forumclosed/atupusito-huoramu/appsheetdezuo-raretaapurinoji-zhong-guan-li-yarogushou-ji-fang-fa-nituite), [【AppSheet使い方】作成者を自動で特定する方法](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-WDws5L5mQ), [プロパティ サービス](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties?hl=ja) おそらく希望するようなGoogleから割り当てられた「ユーザーを一意に特定出来る情報」というものは扱えなさそうです。 そうした情報をGoogleとは関係無しに利用者間で独自に制定しておき、それをプロパティー情報として追加しておくくらいでしょうか。

Comment: やはりAPIなどでまとめて取得するのは難しいようですね。提案いただいたような他の管理方法を検討します。ご返信ありがとうございます。